# Difference in rows with NULL values

Tags: mysql

I have a bunch of rows that have a `position` column, which can be an `integer` or `NULL`.

The rows are sequential in date and what I'm looking to do is to get the number of rows where the `position` field is different from the previous day.

I have something like the following: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=c67fed3a0b65f875fec1cf7d1992b69b

This works great, but the problem is, the `position` can be `NULL` and the following doesn't work: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=f61b5407f178210bc50aadfd3427639c

Is there a way to modify my query, so it will also include rows that are `NULL`?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your post in order  to include sample input data, existing queries, expected result set as well formatted text. This will make the post considerably more readable and you will have better chances getting a correct answer.

Comment: @sipher_z Your query will not do what you expect.  You seem to be assuming that `1 != null` is true.  In fact, `1 != null` is `null` and will count as zero in your sum.  Here's a fiddle to illustrate that any comparison involving `null`s is false:  http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=50a31a771a52ff281cafa1efacb2c98a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your second examples works as well if you change the following:

- In Create Table make the position column "nullable" by removing "not null"
- Remove the quotations from 'NULL' when inserting it
- Change the sum as follows

SUM(CASE WHEN IFNULL(r1.`position`,0) != IFNULL(r2.`position`,0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=bd00e6ed47872d05f544842ade631f6a

Comment: Hi thanks for that. I updated the example with correct columns and data. In your example, it is returning `0` rows. As `2015-05-16` is `NULL` and `2015-05-17` is `22`,  I'd expect the output of the query to be `1` since the values are different..

Comment: I updated my answer an the fiddle and got it working. The comparison of r1 and r2's position is null when one value is null.

Answer (score 0):

While Insert remove `''` from null like below

```
    INSERT INTO `rankings` (`id`, `position`, `date`, `ranking_id`) VALUES
  ('1', '22', '2015-05-14', '1'),
  ('2', '22', '2015-05-15', '1'),
  ('3', null , '2015-05-16',  '1'),
  ('4', '22', '2015-05-17',  '1');
```

Try the below query

```
SELECT r1.`date`, SUM(CASE WHEN r1.`position` != r2.`position` THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as daily_changes
FROM `rankings` r1
LEFT JOIN `rankings` r2
  ON r1.`date` = r2.`date` + 1
 AND r1.`ranking_id` = r2.`ranking_id`
WHERE  r1.position IS NOT NULL OR r2.position IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY r1.`date`
order by r1.`date` DESC
limit 1
```

Comment: I need to include the NULL values as they are different from an integer. So in the above example row with id of 3, is different to row with id of 4 and thus, therefore the result will be 4